# How do I run custom frameworks on swift playgrounds using macOS Mojave and Xcode 10

Tags: swift, frameworks, swift-playground, xcode10, swift4.2

I'm developing a framework in swift targeting iOS devices. The usual pipeline include add a playground to the framework in order to test some functionalities. However, since the last update to macOS Mojave I always get messages like

```
No such module 'FrameWorkName'
```

I tried some solutions that I found on the internet, like create a workspace and add the framework and the playground, but even then it's not working. Keep in mind that the exactly same piece of code ran flawlessly on the previous OS.

How do I add custom frameworks to swift playgrounds in macOS Mojave with Xcode 10? Also, is there a better way to test custom frameworks? I understand that the swift playgrounds are trying to mimic the Jupiter-notebook style of coding, and that is awesome, but it stills need some improvement.

Answer (score 1):

3rd party frameworks can’t simply be included in a playground

There is a way to solve it. It is well described in [Paul Ardeleanu's post on Medium](https://medium.com/@pardel/using-3rd-party-frameworks-in-xcode-10-playgrounds-97aa0c3f56e0)

Comment: Except that this "way to solve" didn't solve anything. Stills can't run custom frameworks in playground with Mojave...